# @timestamp range query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Can I make a range query on default `timestamp` field ignoring `date` values i.e. using only time in timestamp - say 2 hours of each day?

My intentions are to search for all the documents but exclude the documents indexed between 9 PM and 12 AM (I have seen example with date ranges in filtering).

timestamp example stands following:

```
"@timestamp": [
                  "2015-12-21T15:18:17.120Z"
               ]
```

Elasticsearch version: 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

My first idea would be to use the date math in Elasticsearch query, e.g. if you run your query at 1PM, this would work:

```
{
  "query": {
      "range" : {
            "@timestamp" : {
                "gte": "now-16h/h", 
                "lte": "now-1h/h"

            }
        }
  }
}
```

(watch out for the timezone though).

As far as I know, the only other possibility would be to use [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-script-filter.html).

Please note also that you are running a **very** old version of Elasticsearch.

**Edit** If you need simply absolute date, then check how your `@timestamp` field look, and use the same format, for instance on my Elasticsearch, it would be:

```
{
  "query": {
      "range" : {
            "@timestamp" : {
                "gte": "2015-03-20T01:21:00.01Z", 
                "lte": "2015-03-21T01:12:00.04Z"

            }
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: intentionally, I wrote a date with year 2015 (its not like I am querying every day, I can query for a year old data)

Comment: Basically you just need to be careful as how are formatted your date, then you can simply use the same formatting with a range querw, see my edited version